# phpWhois script not getting complete data from Godaddy

Tags: php

I'm using phpWhois project from Github to echo domain WHOIS data. This is [the script](https://github.com/phpWhois/phpWhois).

When I run this script on localhost, and search a domain registered via Godaddy, it show me complete details of the domain.

But, when i use the script on live server and, , and search a domain registered via Godaddy. it show me less details of the domain.
Only the problem coming with Godaddy hosted domains.

Output on localhost (frauzy.com):

```
Domain Name: frauzy.com
Registry Domain ID: 2055465214_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN
Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.godaddy.com
Registrar URL: http://www.godaddy.com
Update Date: 2016-08-27T15:12:14Z
Creation Date: 2016-08-27T15:12:14Z
Registrar Registration Expiration Date: 2017-08-27T15:12:14Z
Registrar: GoDaddy.com, LLC
Registrar IANA ID: 146
Registrar Abuse Contact Email: abuse@godaddy.com
Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: +1.4806242505
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited http://www.icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
Domain Status: clientUpdateProhibited http://www.icann.org/epp#clientUpdateProhibited
Domain Status: clientRenewProhibited http://www.icann.org/epp#clientRenewProhibited
Domain Status: clientDeleteProhibited http://www.icann.org/epp#clientDeleteProhibited
Registry Registrant ID: Not Available From Registry
Registrant Name: Arbaaz Khan
Registrant Organization: 
Registrant Street: 497/2 shastri nagar
Registrant City: kanpur
Registrant State/Province: Uttar Pradesh
Registrant Postal Code: 208005
Registrant Country: IN
Registrant Phone: +91.8932857856
Registrant Phone Ext: 
Registrant Fax: 
Registrant Fax Ext: 
Registrant Email: frauzydotcom@gmail.com
Registry Admin ID: Not Available From Registry
Admin Name: Arbaaz Khan
Admin Organization: 
Admin Street: 497/2 shastri nagar
Admin City: kanpur
Admin State/Province: Uttar Pradesh
Admin Postal Code: 208005
Admin Country: IN
Admin Phone: +91.8932857856
Admin Phone Ext: 
Admin Fax: 
Admin Fax Ext: 
Admin Email: frauzydotcom@gmail.com
Registry Tech ID: Not Available From Registry
Tech Name: Arbaaz Khan
Tech Organization: 
Tech Street: 497/2 shastri nagar
Tech City: kanpur
Tech State/Province: Uttar Pradesh
Tech Postal Code: 208005
Tech Country: IN
Tech Phone: +91.8932857856
Tech Phone Ext: 
Tech Fax: 
Tech Fax Ext: 
Tech Email: frauzydotcom@gmail.com
Name Server: NS77.DOMAINCONTROL.COM
Name Server: NS78.DOMAINCONTROL.COM
DNSSEC: unsigned
URL of the ICANN WHOIS Data Problem Reporting System: http://wdprs.internic.net/
>>> Last update of WHOIS database: 2016-09-13T08:00:00Z <<<
For more information on Whois status codes, please visit https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/epp-status-codes-2014-06-16-en
The data contained in GoDaddy.com, LLC's WhoIs database,
while believed by the company to be reliable, is provided "as is"
with no guarantee or warranties regarding its accuracy. This
information is provided for the sole purpose of assisting you
in obtaining information about domain name registration records.
Any use of this data for any other purpose is expressly forbidden without the prior written
permission of GoDaddy.com, LLC. By submitting an inquiry,
you agree to these terms of usage and limitations of warranty. In particular,
you agree not to use this data to allow, enable, or otherwise make possible,
dissemination or collection of this data, in part or in its entirety, for any
purpose, such as the transmission of unsolicited advertising and
and solicitations of any kind, including spam. You further agree
not to use this data to enable high volume, automated or robotic electronic
processes designed to collect or compile this data for any purpose,
including mining this data for your own personal or commercial purposes. 
Please note: the registrant of the domain name is specified
in the "registrant" section. In most cases, GoDaddy.com, LLC 
is not the registrant of domain names listed in this database.
NServer
ns77.domaincontrol.com
ns78.domaincontrol.com
```

Output on live server (frauzy.com):

```
Domain Name: frauzy.com
Registrar URL: http://www.godaddy.com
Registrant Name: Arbaaz Khan
Registrant Organization: 
Name Server: NS77.DOMAINCONTROL.COM
Name Server: NS78.DOMAINCONTROL.COM
DNSSEC: unsigned

For complete domain details go to:
http://who.godaddy.com/whoischeck.aspx?domain=frauzy.com

The data contained in GoDaddy.com, LLC's WhoIs database,
while believed by the company to be reliable, is provided "as is"
with no guarantee or warranties regarding its accuracy.  This
information is provided for the sole purpose of assisting you
in obtaining information about domain name registration records.
Any use of this data for any other purpose is expressly forbidden without the prior written
permission of GoDaddy.com, LLC.  By submitting an inquiry,
you agree to these terms of usage and limitations of warranty.  In particular,
you agree not to use this data to allow, enable, or otherwise make possible,
dissemination or collection of this data, in part or in its entirety, for any
purpose, such as the transmission of unsolicited advertising and
and solicitations of any kind, including spam.  You further agree
not to use this data to enable high volume, automated or robotic electronic
processes designed to collect or compile this data for any purpose,
including mining this data for your own personal or commercial purposes. 

Please note: the registrant of the domain name is specified
in the "registrant" section.  In most cases, GoDaddy.com, LLC 
is not the registrant of domain names listed in this database.
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who get here wondering why they can't get full "whois" data from GoDaddy from some addresses but possibly can from others:

This is actually a case of GoDaddy deciding to not return full "whois" data via the normal "whois" channels. They've blacklisted entire blocks of IP addresses that they'll no longer provide "whois" data to, on the grounds of "they've abused our service in the past". Which is complete BS of course. They've even blocked our own IP addresses from being able to do 'whois' queries about our very own domain names, forcing us to go to their web site to validate that our 'whois' data is correct. Which is the point -- they're just trying to drive traffic to their web site, where they can then try to give you the hard sell of services offered by GoDaddy. Tx Thanks, GoDaddy!

Source: http://domainnamewire.com/2011/01/04/go-daddy-explains-whois-blocking/